# Удаление содержимого div html

Tags: jquery, html

Есть div, в него вставляю данные, которые приходят от ajax запроса:

```
        function onAjaxSuccess(data)
        {
             $("#divShow").append(data);
        }
```

Нужна функция для очистки содержимого div, попробовал так:

```
        function DeletePrice()
        {
            $("#divShow").remove();
        }
```

Содержимое удаляется, но теперь вставка данных возможна только после обновления страницы, я так понимаю, что DeletePrice удаляет сам блок, а не его содержимое.

Вопрос: как удалить **содержимое** div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для того чтобы удалить всех детей элемента в jQuery есть [**метод empty**](https://api.jquery.com/empty/).

```
$('#divShow').empty();
```